# How to play online radio in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, iostream

I need to play online radio in my application. The url is "http://v5.player.abacast.com/v5.1/player/?uid=6132".and I am using below code for playing online radio.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://v5.player.abacast.com/v5.1/player/?uid=6132"]];
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
player.view.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

and I also use iphonestreamplayer both are not working.

Comment: The URL is linked to a Flash player, you will need to URL of the stream.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get URL of the stream..?

Comment: No I can not, maybe the radio provider can. Or you could scan your netwerk activity and look for the stream there.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Send Live Streams or Video on Demand, with Optional Encryption

The playlists and media segment files can be used for video on demand or streaming radio, for example.

For live streams, Apple provides a free tool to make media segment files and playlists from live MPEG-2 transport streams carrying H.264 video, AAC audio, or MP3 audio. There are a number of hardware and software encoders that can create MPEG-2 transport streams carrying MPEG-4 video and AAC audio in real time.

Radio Streaming can be done by [HTTP LIVE STREAMING](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) 
First You have to download the http live streaming tool from apple.developers. With the help of mediastreamsegmenter you can make .ts file and .m3u8 (the index file). with help of index file you can play your live radio.